# How to avoid printing array when printing array elements in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

My index action in my controller is something like this:

```
@dbs = somearray
```

My view corresponding to this action (index.html.erb) is trying to print only the elements of the `@dbs` array but it prints no only the elements individually but the entire array as well (which I want to avoid printing). The code printing in index.html.erb is:

```
<%= for db in @dbs do %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= db %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

This prints:

```
["ele1","ele2","ele3"]
----
ele1
----
ele2
----
ele3
----
```

How can I avoid printing: `["ele1","ele2","ele3"]`? I just want to print the table with the elements!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The construction `<%= %>` is printing into output, `<% %>` doesn't print into output. Just change one line to this:

```
<% for db in @dbs do %>
```